# Android App uninstalled suddenly

Tags: android, uninstallation

A few Users say my application uninstalls itself, or I get messages like "This morning application disappeared and tapping the icon I get a message not installed".

Did anyone had this issue? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tapping the icon getting app not installed indicates the shortcut is broken; the app itself may not be uninstalled.  For example if you have recently done an update to your app, you could have broken shortcuts by changing the name of an activity as described here -- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html